# How to get rid of this error: "WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2."

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, jboss, netbeans-8

I am trying to create a simple web service by referring this site : http://www.connect2java.com/webservices/jax-rs-applicationpath-annotationno-web-xml-example-in-jersey/

I am using

> NetBeans IDE 8.0.2
>
> Java 8.0 JDK 1.7
>
> JBoss Server

Here is my code :

RestfulApplicationPathAnnotationExample.java:

```
package com.connect2java.RestfulApplicationPathAnnotationExample;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class RestfulApplicationPathAnnotationExample {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)     
     public Response sayHello() {

        String str ="<H1>Hi!!! welcome to @ApplicationPath Annotation Example in Restful webservices  </H1> ";

        return Response.status(200).entity(str).build();

    }

}
```

MyApplication.java:

```
package com.connect2java.RestfulApplicationPathAnnotationExample;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

    @ApplicationPath("resources")
    public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
        public MyApplication() {
            packages("com.connect2java.RestfulApplicationPathAnnotationExample");
        }

    }
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

run output:

[image: run output]

error displayed at server:

```
13:06:39,832 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] undeploy, ctxPath=/RestfulApplicationPathAnnotationExample, warUrl=.../tmp/deploy/tmp7253522143789622225RestfulApplicationPathAnnotationExample-exp.war/
13:06:40,253 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/RestfulApplicationPathAnnotationExample, warUrl=.../tmp/deploy/tmp3990284126749515271RestfulApplicationPathAnnotationExample-exp.war/
13:06:40,316 INFO  [WebappClassLoader] validateJarFile(C:\jboss\server\default\.\tmp\deploy\tmp3990284126749515271RestfulApplicationPathAnnotationExample-exp.war\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

Program structure:

[image]

I get "Hello World" output in the webpage at this URL:

> http://localhost:8080/RestfulApplicationPathAnnotationExample/

But when I try this URL:

> http://localhost:8080/RestfulApplicationPathAnnotationExample/resources/hello

I get this error message:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /RestfulApplicationPathAnnotationExample/resources/hello

The requested resource (/RestfulApplicationPathAnnotationExample/resources/hello) is not available.
```

Can someone help me out please ?

Comment: Please do **not** provide your code in images, but [edit] them into your question! Like that debugging can be done by friendly other users by copy pasting and not typing from your images!

Answer (score 0):

> WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2.”

This is a warning (not an error). You should not deploy any jar containg `javax.servlet` classes. Container will ignore it. Just remove `javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar` from your `.war`

About your path issue, seems jersey is omitting `@ApplicationPath("resources")`. Try to add `/` prefix like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22972319/6371459) `@ApplicationPath("/resources")`